# Download SVG image from URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to download the SVG image from the URL. I tried to convert the image into `Uint8List` and then used [ImageGallerySaver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) to download the image.

But I am getting an error

> PlatformException (PlatformException(error, decodeByteArray(image, 0,
> image.size) must not be null, null, java.lang.NullPointerException:
> decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.size) must not be null

The same code works if i try to download png formatted image.

Following are the code i am using.

```
String url = 'https://qodevault-staging.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/qrcodes/6136f35c3a5e9824329fdd8166d01715.svg'
final bytes = await kNetworkImageToBytes(url);
kSaveImageFromBytes(imgData: bytes, name: 'qrcode');
```

Function to parse network image to bytes

```
///converts network image (Except for svg) to [Uint8List]
Future<Uint8List> kNetworkImageToBytes(String imageUrl) async {
  try {
    var response = await Dio().get(
      imageUrl,
      options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
    );
    return Uint8List.fromList(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

Function to download image from bytes

```
Future<void> kSaveImageFromBytes({
  required Uint8List imgData,
  required String name,
  bool appendRandomString = true,
}) async {
  final random = generateRandomString(10);
  final filename = appendRandomString ? '${name}_$random' : name;
  final bool hasPermission =
      await PermissionHandler.requestPermission(Permission.storage);
  if (!hasPermission) throw 'Permission not granted';
  final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
    imgData,
    quality: 100,
    name: 'QV_$filename',
  );
  print(result);
  if (result is Map) {
    if (result['isSuccess'].toString() == 'false') {
      throw 'Error saving image';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: SVGs are not supported as images, at least on Android. Therefore, you cannot save them to the gallery.

Comment: tried converting it to base64 and to png format. Still having same issue

Comment: Base64 is not an image format.

Comment: i know. I mean i tried drawing the svg image from url to canvas and converting it into png (converting to base64 is one of its process) but it generates corrupted image.

Comment: Then solve the corruption issue first. Edit your question to include detail on what you've tried to do to solve this problem.

Comment: it was not solved, That is why i am asking the question here

Comment: You need to solve the issue with whatever conversion method you're using causing corruption. You need to edit your question to include the details of your attempts at solving this.

Answer (score 0):

with Flutter 3.7.8 packages: davinci, flutter_svg, image_gallery_saver

```
import 'package:davinci/core/davinci_capture.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<void> _onClick(String url) async {
    final response = await Dio().get(url);

    final imageBytes = await DavinciCapture.offStage(
      SvgPicture.string(
        response.data,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
      returnImageUint8List: true,
      openFilePreview: false,
      saveToDevice: false,
    );
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
      imageBytes,
      name: "QRCode",
    );

    setState(() {
      isSuccess = result['isSuccess'];
    });
  }

  bool? isSuccess;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: isSuccess != null
            ? Text('isSuccess: $isSuccess')
            : ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _onClick(
                    'https://qodevault-staging.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/qrcodes/6136f35c3a5e9824329fdd8166d01715.svg'),
                child: const Text('Here'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]